# Using Codemirror in Django

Tags: python, django, codemirror

I'm trying to add CodeMirror editor to my Django application.
I'm using following code in script:

```
var myCodeMirror = new CodeMirror(document.body, {
      lineNumbers: true,
      value: "print 'Hello!'",
      mode:  "python",
      theme : 'mbo'
});
myCodeMirror.focus();
document.getElementById('frame').innerHTML=myCodeMirror.getValue();
```

But I don't get editor on the page as a result, only value `'Hello'`.

Please help.

Comment: More details will be needed.  For example how you import CodeMirror to your page ? Also, have you checked your javascript console for error messages?

Comment: I have installed codemirror, so I just use these scripts:                                                                  <script type="text/javascript" src="codeMirror-5.4/lib/codemirror.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="codeMirror-5.4/mode/clike/clike.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="codeMirror-5.4/mode/python/python.js"></script> I have tried to execute the same code via localhost and it works, but it does not in Django. I get this in the best case: http://pokit.org/get/?4ffa6b45925fbad79e8cf02d46a7ee95.jpg and no errors.

Answer (score 0):

From the codemirror front page:

```
<!-- Create a simple CodeMirror instance -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/codemirror.css">
<script src="lib/codemirror.js"></script>
<script>
  var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(myTextarea, {
    lineNumbers: true
  });
</script>
```

Also, in the page links for django, I would expect these resources to be declared static(assuming you got your scripts in the static dir of the project) using the tag:

```
<script src="{% static 'lib/codemirror.js' %}"></script>
```

Comment: In a hurry i copied wrong links, yes, I use scripts like this:     <script  src="{% static "codeMirror-5.4/lib/codemirror.js"%}"></script>
 <script  src="{% static "codeMirror-5.4/mode/clike/clike.js"%}"></script>
 <script  src="{% static "codeMirror-5.4/mode/python/python.js"%}"></script> I saw that code, but still have a problem, thanks anyway.

Comment: What about the javascript console of the browser? Do you get anything there when loading the page?

Comment: Also, this is probably silly, but restart django if you added new files,just in case ^_^

Comment: Nothing.
I have tried some new options, so I see now that my problem is in loading editor in elements. I have tried to load it using document.body and in direct element via document.getElementById, but it's not working properly. http://pokit.org/get/?b6ae9017b32e34b20feb4c1443915c85.jpg Those numbers are line numbers xD

Comment: Have you tried initializing exactly as the example (for start) using the fromTextArea constructor ? If that works then you can move to different method (if needed)

Comment: I have tried this way, but still..it doesn't work in Django.
 <textarea id="code"></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var myTextarea = document.getElementById('code');
 var myCodeMirror = new CodeMirror.fromTextArea(myTextarea, {
  lineNumbers: true,
  value: "print 'Dobrodosli!'",
  mode:  "python",
  theme : 'mbo'
});
myCodeMirror.focus();


</script>